# Programmatically delete blocks

Tags: blocks, 10

Is there a way to programmatically delete blocks in a Drupal 10 site?

I need to delete the *Powered by Drupal* block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete all instances of the [Powered by Drupal](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21src%21Plugin%21Block%21SystemPoweredByBlock.php/class/SystemPoweredByBlock) block:

```
$blocks = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('block')
  ->loadByProperties(['plugin' => 'system_powered_by_block']);
foreach ($blocks as $block) {
  $block->delete();
}
```

Comment: Thats perfect, thank you so much.